# replace "[ with [ and ]" with ] json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a JSON as below:

```
[{"type":"Point","coordinates":"[-77.03,38.90]"},"properties":{"city":3,"url":"xyz.com"}]
```

I want to replace `"[` with `[` and `]"` with `]`

Comment: That's a dumb idea. What you should do is **decode** the array, convert the **variable types** (which will remove the quotes if you convert a string to an array etc) and then **re-encode it** as JSON again.

Comment: Do you mean you want to turn the value of `coordinates` into a real array, rather than a string?

Comment: Forget my last comment. Where do you get this JSON from? A file? An ajax call?

Comment: It's not JSON. It's invalid mess of strings, array and object.

Comment: Are you looking for `json_decode` ?

Comment: @Yogesh I have tried json.replace("\"[","[");

Comment: @ojovirtual : I am getting JSON From File.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra : I am not looking for decode I am looking for to remove **"** from **"[**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 $yourJson = [{"type":"Point","coordinates":"[-77.03,38.90]"},"properties":{"city":3,"url":"xyz.com"}];
 $jsonString=preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $yourJson);
    $stringReplace=str_replace('"[', '[', $jsonString);
    $stringReplace=str_replace(']"', ']', $stringReplace);
    echo $stringReplace;
```

Answer (score 0):

from the comment it seems you are putting additional **quote** *"* in replace try this

```
json = json.replace("\"[","[");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [following regex](http://www.regexper.com/#%22%28%5C%5B%5B%5E%22%5C%5D%5D%2a%5C%5D%29%22):

```
str.replace(/"(\[[^"\]]*\])"/, "$1");
```

where `str` is the input string. This will match `"[` followed by a string of any characters that are not `"` and `]`, followed by `]"` and drop the two `"` at the extremes. In your case it will turn `"[-77.03,38.90]"` into `[-77.03,38.90]`.

Aside from that, whoever coded what is returning the string in the question should be fired **immediately**.

Comment: its giving this kind of error : Expected one of ?:, ?=, ?!, ^, *, +, ?, {, {,, (, [, ., \, $, |, ) at line 1, column 3 (byte 3) after (

Comment: which javascript runtime are you using?